# In Titanium Ti.XML.parseString is Undefined Why?

Tags: titanium

i have a problem with parseString i get the following error :

TypeError : cannot call method "parseString" of undefined.

I just have a XML file, look at this :

```
var setupXml = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + "/config.xml"); 
var fluxXml = setupXml.read().text; 
var doc = Ti.XML.parseString(fluxXml); 
myNodeList = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("configuration"); 
for(var i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {     
  alert(myNodeList.item(i).getElementsByTagName("login").text); 
}
```

Comment: Check your file path first.. is it correct? if(setupXml.exists()){ }

Comment: If this is the first time you've used the XML namespace you might need to clear your Build folder and run it again.  If on Android simply update your tiapp.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the "/" at the beginning of `"/config.xml"`